# Не работает пример из документации Python

Tags: python, ide, signal

Читаю документацию про модуль "signal", там есть следующий код:

```
import signal, os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Signal handler called with signal', signum)
    raise OSError("Couldn't open device!")

# Set the signal handler and a 5-second alarm
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(5)

# This open() may hang indefinitely
fd = os.open('/dev/ttyS0', os.O_RDWR)

signal.alarm(0)          # Disable the alarm
```

Который при копировании в IDE не работает. 
Ошибка в первой же строчке про `signal` (не считая `import`), пишется

> signal is not callable

Версии совпадают, проверял. 
 Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: 1) Добавьте полный стек. Ошибка вида ` is not callable ` возникает, когда у объекта вызывают круглые скобки, а тот не является ни функцией, ни классом, ни функтором (объектом, что реализует магический метод `__call__`), а у вас не вижу в коде `signal()`. 2) А на какой ОС запускаете? На windows?

Comment: Запускаю на Windows. А код целиком взят из примера, я ничего не изменял.

Comment: Как называется файл?

Comment: /dev/ttyS0 на windows работать не будет.

Comment: signal.py. Начинаю подозревать, что это и является причиною. Попробую изменить.

Comment: @Voolfeh да, это и есть причина.

Comment: @Эникейщик, так и оказалось. Однако, компилятор теперь ругается, что у модуля "signal" нет атрибута 'SIGALRM'

Comment: В windows - нет.

Comment: @Эникейщик понял, спасибо